# Vertical Align on <table> slightly off center... any idea's why?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to center a table vertically within another div, but I'm getting results that seems to be off by a few pixels vertically (in FF at least).

Is there some default values somewhere throwing the vertical align off?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/9hRnp/

Note:The code is produced by Jquery and is to show the problem only so that's why i have width and height values on each `<TD>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a vertical-align:middle to the findpath-content id should solve your problem.

```
#findpath-content {
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}​